# How to modify the BTLE sample code so that it can run on iPhone4?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, iphone-4

Currently I'm working/testing on Bluetooth stuff. I download the sample code from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html). However, I found it can't work on iPhone4, only 4S can work.

I know iPhone4 only has Bluetooth2.1, but I would like to know that is it possible to modify the code so that it can do the same thing on iPhone4, or there's any limitation that I can't do it on iPhone4? It means that we can transfer the data via Bluetooth if BTLE or even only Bluetooth classic is available. Since I am newbie in this area, would anyone suggest how to get started?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you are relatively limited when dealing with Bluetooth < 4.0, but you do have two options:

1. Enroll in the MFI program - long and expensive process (for talking
   to other hardware)
2. Use the GameKit framework - iOS Only communication

You can find the GameKit documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GameKit_Collection/Introduction/Introduction.html but it's much more limiting than CoreBluetooth is.

I hope that this has been helpful.

Comment: Sorry that I may not describe my question clearly. My question is that if Core Bluetooth framework is super set of BT 2.1, why we can't use those APIs which work for old modules? Or they are totally different and no backward compatibility? It means nothing in Core Bluetooth framework can support iPhone4?? Which one is correct?

Comment: You are correct, the BTLE protocol isn't backwards compatible, nothing in CoreBluetooth will support the iPhone 4.

Comment: Daniel, thanks for your comments. I got it. I will find out a new device for BTLE testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get it to work on any iOS device that does not support BTLE. So it's only available for iPhone 4S and newer or iPad 3G and newer.

As explained in the [Core Bluetooth Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html):

> The Core Bluetooth framework provides the classes needed for your iOS
>   and Mac apps to communicate with devices that are equipped with
>   Bluetooth low energy wireless technology.

Comment: It means that even I have iPhone4 w/ Bluetooth 2.1, I can't program it in my app?? But I always think Core Bluetooth framework is abstracts away the low-level details from the Bluetooth 4.0 specification, it's superset of BT 2.1. It means that I still can use those backward compatibility APIs which are working for old modules like iPhone4. But if so why the apple programming guide did not describe which device is supported, just mentioned required iOS version, is there any misunderstanding?

Comment: CoreBluetooth is Bluetooth 4 only this it will not work on a device with a bluetooth 2.1 only chip. And **NO** CoreBluetooth is not backwards compatible. It clearly states that it will only on a device with a BTLE chip. Not thing about the iOS version.

Answer (score 0):

From Apple docs, 
All devices Apple released since the iPhone 4S (including the 4S) will support Bluetooth 4.0. For rest of the device (iPhone 4), you need to work with Core Bluetooth API for same.